# Is it possible to check if a file returns a 404 error if it's on a different server with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube, http-status-code-404

Is it possible to check if a file returns a 404 error if it's on a different server using jQuery/javascript?

I'm using the youtube api to get a HD screenshot for the video I'm embedding, but the JSON that it returns gives no indication of whether a HD screenshot for the video exists.

the url for the screenshot is usually,
http://img.youtube.com/vi/ + video.ID + /maxresdefault.jpg

but when it doesn't exist, i get this ugly low-res gray POS:
http://img.youtube.com/vi/MAyTES9gDAU/maxresdefault.jpg

So, basically, I want to check if the screenshot exists and if not, apply `display: none` to the div that holds it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an `<img>` element pointing to that image, then handle the `onerror` event and hide it.

Comment: This solution does not work. Even though the response status is a 404, the onerror event handler is never triggered.

Answer (score 5):

You can create an `Image` object and handle `onload` and `onerror`. It'll only work for images, mind.

```
function checkExists(imageUrl, callback) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onerror = function() {
        callback(false);
    };

    img.onload = function() {
        callback(true);
    };

    img.src = imageUrl;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
checkExists(yourVideoUrl, function(exists) {
    if(!exists) {
        // Hide the image
    }
});
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/m8aen/)

Comment: This is not working. Youtube returns the little grey image, so the function returns true: http://jsfiddle.net/W8JVA/

Comment: Thanks for this, quick and easy.

Answer (score 1):

minitech's answer works for checking 404's, however...

For the YouTube case, they have their own handling instead of giving you a 404, they give you a "nice" error image.

YouTube has an API that will check if the video ID is valid. Check out this post that tells you how to check if a YouTube video id exists or is valid: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/oAztQ3f1tcM

Once you confirm that the video exists, you can then try to load up the image. If the video *doesn't* exist, you can handle that case however you want.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (mine is in coffeescript).

```
checkImages = ->
  $("img").each ->
    $(this).error ->
      $(this).attr("src", "../default/image.jpg")

$(document).on('page:load', checkImages)
```

I'm guessing the javascript equivalent is something like

```
function checkImages() {
  $("img").each(function() {
    $(this).error(function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "../default/image.jpg");
    });
  });
};

$(document).on("page:load", checkImages);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add extra check for a default gray image:

```
function checkExists(imageUrl, callback) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onerror = function() {
        callback(false);
    };

    img.onload = function() {
        //check for a default (grey) image
        if (this.width == 120) {
           callback(false);
        }else {
           callback(true);
        }
    };

    img.src = imageUrl;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7nv5m48q/)